# Calcul between two rows SQL with conditions

Tags: php, sql, case

I have an SQL database containing invoice data. It includes columns for "sum" and "invoice_id," where the total amount is stored (for sum), and if it's a down payment (invoice_id contained the other invoice id). What I need to do is calculate the sum minus the down payment, if there is one. For example, these two lines represent one project: invoice id 1567 is the down payment, and invoice id 1551 is the final invoice. Here's an image for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAGzr.jpg). The total of both sums needs to be 2902.75 for my PHP function without altering the data in this row.

For now my PHP function to calculate the sum is :

```
$result = Invoice::find_by_sql("
     SELECT 
         sum(invoices."sum") as "summary" 
     FROM 
         invoices 
     WHERE 
         estimate != 1 
     AND due_date < CURDATE() 
 ");
```

So for the exemple of above with the tow lines, I got 4063,65.

PS: I use Codeingniter in PHP framwork for my app : The full php function

```
/**
    ** Get sum of late
    ** return object
    **/
    public static function latePayments($option="")
    {
        if ($option == "all")
        {
            $result = Invoice::find_by_sql("
                SELECT 
                    sum(invoices.`sum`) as `summary` 
                FROM 
                    invoices 
                WHERE 
                    estimate != 1 
                    AND due_date < CURDATE() 
            ");
        }
        else
        {
            $result = Invoice::find_by_sql("
                SELECT 
                    sum(invoices.`sum`) as `summary`
                FROM 
                    invoices 
                WHERE 
                    (status = 'Open' OR status = 'Sent' OR status = 'PartiallyPaid') 
                    AND estimate != 1 
                    AND due_date < CURDATE() 
            ");
        }
        return $result[0]->summary;
    }
}
```

Edit 1 : The link for the sql file of the two lines : [File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3699e9fa298291116e171b4cd6e3b6ab20230911093425/d8006e)

Comment: Could you please share your data as text not image ?

Comment: No parse error for that function?

Comment: The code you've shown us here will error out in PHP (and if it didn't, it would fail in the DBMS).

Comment: @SelVazi I upload the file in the main post

Comment: @brombeer I use the codeigniter framwork, i edit the main post and add this info :)

Comment: @symcbean I edit the main post and add the codeigniter framwork and the full function

Comment: @Flavien i do not really understand your database design. It look like you store invoice and payment inside the same table ? Is it ? If you want to properly store invoice and payment, you will have to split it between two table in first.

Comment: @ThomasL I use the Freelance Cockpit CRM, so I can't edit such like this... But if I'm correct, we only have the statue, not the amount of payment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some Active Record, or some other ORM. I think it would be easier to find the invoices and subtract using PHP, not SQL. Something like this:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find_by_id(<some_id>);
$down_payment_id = $invoice->invoice_id;
if ($down_payment_id === null) {
    return $invoice->sum;
}
$down_payment = Invoice::find_by_id($down_payment_id);
return $invoice->sum - $down_payment->sum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with the full function i put on the main post, and the "find_by_sql", how can I do ?